# MySql - ¿Como listar datos agrupados de una tabla con ciertas condiciones?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

Adjunto la tabla y sus registros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que los registro que sean de la misma fecha me los agrupe en uno solo pero con la disponibilidad "0" si es que alguna de esas fechas tuviese ese valor. De lo contrario que me los agrupe con disponibilidad "1".

El resultado que espero es para listarlos así:

```html
<table id="tabla" style="text-align: center;">
<tr>
<td>Fecha</td>
<td>Disponibilidad</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-07-03</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-07-04</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias!!

Comment: Hola!!! intentaste algo??? con un pequeño truquito jugando con min se puede lograr facilmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hay que haces es agrupar por fecha, y como se quieren las fechas que por lo menos tengan un cero, nada mejor que aprovecharse un poco del álgebra de conjuntos y mostrar el mínimo del campo Disponibilidad...

De esa forma, si el campo disponibilidad tiene todos 1, entonces va a mostrar un 1, pero si hay algún 0, entonces va a mostrar 0.

```
SELECT fechas.Fecha, MIN(fechas.Disponibilidad) FROM fechas 
WHERE fechas.Fecha >='2020-07-02'
GROUP BY fechas.Fecha
```

Comment: Amigo me sirvió mucho tu respuesta! Te lo agradezco de corazón. Saludos!!!

Answer (score -2):

Se me ocurre que uses la cláusula GROUP BY:

```
SELECT * FROM fechas 
WHERE fechas.Fecha >='2020-07-02'
GROUP BY fechas.Fecha, fechas.Disponibilidad
```

El asterísco muestra todas las columnas, si quieres sólo Fecha y Disponibilidad lo haces así:

```
SELECT Fecha, Disponibilidad FROM fechas 
WHERE fechas.Fecha >='2020-07-02'
GROUP BY fechas.Fecha, fechas.Disponibilidad
```

**PARECE QUE LA SOLUCIÓN QUE APORTÉ AGRUPA POR FECHAS PERO EN EL CASO QUE EXISTA DISTINTA DISPONIBILIDAD PARA UNA FECHA MUESTRA AMBAS Y NO ERA LO QUE SE PRETENDE.**

En esta nueva solución que aporto creo que se comporta como es esperado:

```
    SELECT Fecha, MIN(Disponibilidad) AS Disponibilidad
    FROM fechas
    GROUP BY Fecha
```

Comment: esto va a mostrar cualquier disponibilidad.. no anda....

Comment: Si para una fecha hay disponibilidad 0 y 1 es verdad que al agrupar por fecha y luego por disponibilidad mostraría ambas; de forma que si sólo se quiere la de disponibilidad 0 qué sentido tiene mostrar disponibilidad 1 para otras fechas. En el WHERE se puede forzar para que filtre sólo disponibilidad 0.

Comment: En ese caso no va a mostrar las fechas con disponibilidad 1.. Esta no es la forma de hacerlo. esto que estas mostrando no funciona de ninguna manera. Como puse en un comentario, se hace con min...

Comment: si lo de adentro (la solucion que plantee yo) ya lo hace, para que haces todo lo de afuera? si agrupas por fecha, el distinct despues no agrega nada... :/

Comment: En mi SAMPLE que he creado para testar el código sí que  es necesario. Si lo quito el resultado no es el esperado.

Comment: Sí es verdad, llevas toda la razón. Basta con el SELECT interior. Lo editaré para simplificar.

Comment: Cuando creas un ejemplo que dices que te funciona, compartilo, asi podemos ver si es cierto o tiene algun problema, y de paso aprendemos todos. ;)

Comment: El que he puesto funcionaba de la misma forma, pero sí que es verdad que llevas la razón que todo era simplificable.